# Django forms want to auto-save user, client and datetime

Tags: python, django, forms, autosave

I need some help.

In my models.py I have a table for Note. What I want to to do with this table is to create a form where a user could enter some notes in a text field for a particular client.

**models.py**

```
class Note(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User)
    note = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)
```

Now when the user enters a note, they should **only** see the note text field. Once the form has been submitted the form should auto-save the date+time to what ever the time and date is.
I seem to be having with the user field. Once the form has been submitted the authenticated user should be auto save. I am not really sure how you can do this. I also want to auto-save the client as well so who ever client's page you got to `(r'^clients/(?P<client_id>\d+)/$', views.get_client)`, auto-save from that client.

Here is what I wrote in my forms.py

**forms.py**

```
class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Note
        exclude = ('client','user','datetime')
```

And here my views as well.

**Views.py**

```
def add_notes(request, client_id):
    client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
    notes = client.note_set.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.NoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(True)
            request.user.message_set.create(message = "Note is successfully added.")
            return HttpResponse("<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">window.opener.location = window.opener.location; window.close();</script>")
    else:
        form = forms.NoteForm()
    return render_to_response('note_form.html', {'form':form, 'client':client,'notes':notes}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    if form.is_valid():
        note = form.save(commit=False)
        note.user = request.user
        note.client = client
        note.save()
```

Comment: Although all of these answers may be correct there can only be one winner. Daniels method seems to be the best method for this problem.

Comment: @Shehzad009 I agree that Daniel provided the best answer, but I'm quite sure this code should be in form, not in view.

Answer (score 7):

```
class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Note
        exclude = ('client','user','datetime')

    def __init__(self, client, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.client = client
        self.user = user
        super(NoteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self):
        note = super(NoteForm, self).save(commit=False)
        note.user = self.user
        note.client = self.client
        note.save()
        return note
```

And in view:

```
form = forms.NoteForm(client, request.user, request.POST)
```

Comment: Best answer IMO, this code is best in the Model Form itself so the .save() override can be recycled, instead of typing it in every view later on.

Answer (score 1):

First, for your models:

```
datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

is better.

For your view now, I think you should write:

```
note = Note(client=client, user=request.user)
form = forms.NoteForm(instance=note)
```

Comment: Why `auto_now_add` is better?

Comment: auto_now_add and auto_now make fields not editable when one of this attribute is True. Just more readable.